# Proguard not obfuscating string and class names

Tags: android, android-proguard

**This is the first time I am using proguard**. I am able to obfuscate almost everything in my apk. **But string and class names are not getting obfuscated**. How can I make sure that class names gets obfuscated in my apk.

Here is my `proguard-rule.pro`

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
   public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
   public static int v(...);
   public static int i(...);
   public static int w(...);
   public static int d(...);
   public static int e(...);
}
-dontwarn org.androidannotations.api.rest.**
-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ignite.tsa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Can someone provide with a proper `proguard-rule.pro` file for obfuscating the `AppCompat` and other android libraries present.

Comment: You say that "certain part are not getting obfuscated", but we do not know what the "certain part" is.

Comment: You need to clarify what you expect to be obfuscated but isn't. Some things need to be non-obfuscated for android to work.

Comment: I am able to see the packaging structure. I am able to see the  `appcompat` files easily and other certain libraries.

Comment: @Kiskae Have updated my question and now its more specific.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to see the appcompat files easily

Well, sure. You typed into your ProGuard rules the following lines:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

If you want classes in `android.support.v7` to be obfuscated (and removed if they are unused), you need to get rid of those lines, or replace them with something that is better tailored to indicate *specifically* what you want to keep.

Comment: I want to obfuscate my Activity,BroadcastReceiver,Service and Fragment class names. Mostly I need string and class obfuscation.

Comment: @Hiren: ProGuard cannot do that, because those classes are all instantiated via reflection. It is possible that a commercial obfuscators (e.g., DexGuard) can handle this. Personally, I think that you are wasting your time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable reply.

Comment: Dexguard seems to very costly. Any cheaper alternative ?

Comment: @Hiren: Since I find obfuscation to be pointless, I have not researched all of the products in the marketplace, sorry.

Comment: Thanks again. Looking forward to subscribe your **The Busy Coder's Guide for Android Development**